# C# Access denied to path c:\windows\System32

Tags: c#

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\sru\SRUDB' is denied.

I am an administrator, I have access to the folder, the admin launch is registered in the manifest...

```
DownloadAndMoveFile("https://test.com/SRUDB", @"C:\Windows\System32\sru\SRUDB", "SRUDB.dat");

private void DownloadAndMoveFile(string url, string downloadPath, string newFilePath)
{
     using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
     {
         client.DownloadFile(url, downloadPath);
     }

     String filename = @"C:\Windows\System32\sru\SRUDB.dat";

     WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
     var account = new NTAccount(identity.Name);

     FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(filename);
     fSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
     fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

     File.SetAccessControl(filename, fSecurity);

     String filename1 = @"C:\Windows\System32\sru\SRUDB";

     WindowsIdentity identity1 = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
     var account1 = new NTAccount(identity1.Name);

     FileSecurity fSecurity1 = File.GetAccessControl(filename1);
     fSecurity1.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account1, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
     fSecurity1.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account1, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

     File.SetAccessControl(filename1, fSecurity1);

     string movePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(downloadPath), newFilePath);
     File.Delete(@"C:\WINDOWS\System32\sru\SRUDB.dat");
     File.Move(downloadPath, movePath);
}
```

Comment: That's not a directory that Administrator normally has access to unless you've modified the permissions.

Comment: Does it *really* need to live under "C:\Windows\System32\"?

Comment: I changed the permissions didn't help...

Comment: In general, the files in System32 are so heavily protected that you can't do anything. If you run a process as `System` and replace a file, you can observe the original version being resurrected

Comment: if i do this with batch file this good work

Comment: It probably knows that file came from the outside of the OS. Usually files like this have that "unlock" checkbox. This is why your batch might work but not web client

Comment: I did not understand the essence of the essence how do I fix the code so that it works